# Product Rule and Differentiation with logarithms

Tags: derivatives, logarithms

I'm currently trying to understand the math in this paper Xu et al. ([Neural Image Caption Generation with Visual Attention](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.03044.pdf)).

From the paper:

There is an objective function $L_s$ which is a variational lower bound on the marginal log-likelihood $p(y|a)$

\begin{align*}
L_s = \sum_s p(s|a) log[ p(y|s,a)] \leq log [\sum_s p(s|a)p(y|s,a)] = log [p(y|a)]
\end{align*}

The objective is to derive parameters W by optimising $L_s$

\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial L_s}{\partial W} = \sum_s p(s|a)\left[ \frac{\partial log[p(y|s,a)]}{\partial W} + log[p(y|s,a)] \frac{\partial log[p(s|a)]}{\partial W} \right]
\end{align*}

I found an answer ([2](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2165648)) which explains how to form the variational lower bound on the marginal log-likelihood p(y|a):

From ([2](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2165648)):
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial}{\partial W}L_s &= \sum_s \frac{\partial p(s|a)}{\partial W}\log p(y | s ,  a) + p(s|a) \frac{\partial p(y | s ,a)}{\partial W} \\
&= \sum_s \left( p(s | a)\frac{\partial \log p(s|a)}{\partial W} \right)\log p(y|s , a) + p(s |a)\frac{\partial \log p(y |s,a)}{\partial W} \\
&= \sum_s p(s|a) \left[ \frac{\partial \log p(s|a)}{\partial W}\log p(y| s,a) +   \frac{\partial \log p(y| s,  a )}{\partial W} \right]
\end{align*}

I don't understand how the derivative is formed. 
From my understanding, finding the derivative of $Ls$ using the product rule:

\begin{align*}
f &= p(s|a) \\ 
f' &= \frac{\partial p(s|a)}{\partial W} \\ \\
g &= \log p(y| s,  a )\\
\end{align*}

Why is the derivative of g this:

\begin{align*}
g' &= \frac{\partial p(y| s,  a )}{\partial W}
\end{align*}

and not this:

\begin{align*}
g' &= \frac{1}{p(y| s,  a )} \frac{\partial p(y| s,  a )}{\partial W}
\end{align*}

Secondly, the transition from the first line of the derivative to the second.
When the first term gets multiplied by the log it ends up with $p(s|a)$ out front:
\begin{align*}
p(s|a) \frac{\partial \log p(s|a)}{\partial W}
\end{align*}

Whereas the second term only gets a log introduced:
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial \log p(y |s,a)}{\partial W}
\end{align*}

Why is this?

Thanks!